# inputbox onchange event is not updating state in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React JS and trying to create a CRUD app. In a form, I could able to successfully fetch existing data and bind into forms controls. However, the onchange event of an input box does not seem to update the corresponding state. Sharing the code sample. Any input is highly appreciated.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


function BookEdits() {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [data, setData] = useState("");    
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    
    const params = useParams();    

// Please ignore this part
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      
      event.preventDefault();

      const requestOptions = {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          title: title,
          description: description,
          author: author,
        }),
      };

      
      fetch(`https://localhost:7174/api/books/${params.id}`, requestOptions).then(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response);
          if (!response.ok) alert("Error saving book details");
          else alert("Book details is saved successfully");
          navigate("/BooksList");
        }
      );
    };   
//
  


   useEffect(() => {
       fetch(`https://localhost:7174/api/Books/${params.id}`)
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then(setData);    
   }, []);

// Does not change post onchange event
   console.log(data.title); 

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Title:
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
        <input
          type="text" value={data.title}        
          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>      
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

export default BookEdits;
```

State should update post onchange event. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`data.title` isn't the same as `title`. You call `setTitle`, which changes `title`, but you're logging `data.title`, which isn't the same attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. title returns null while logging and even for data binding. I'm able to do data binding successfully using data.title.

Comment: you are not setting any data here `.then(setData); ` after fetching the data

Comment: Thank you. But, I am able to see the values populated inside the "data" and the control is also populated.